# The detection value $(A^2 + A) $ is:

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&3\\
\end{bmatrix}$
and
$P=\begin{bmatrix}
7&0&2\\
0&1&0\\
2&0&5\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Consider $A = P ^ {-1}DP.$ The detection value $det(A ^ 2 + A)$ is:

Thought about: ${{A}^{2}}={{P}^{-1}}DP{{P}^{-1}}DP={{P}^{-1}}DDP$, so ${{A}^{2}}+A={{P}^{-1}}D(D+{{I}_{3}})P$, and $\det (XY)=\det (X)\det (Y)$

Comment: I am assuming "detection value"  is commonly referred to as "determinant" for English speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the determinant of $D^2+D$ since
$$(P^{-1}DP)^2+P^{-1}DP=P^{-1}(D^2+D)P$$
where you can use the fact that $\det(XY) =\det(X) \det(Y) $ and $\det(P^{-1})=1/\det(P)$. This determinant is trivial to compute as the matrix is diagonal.